# Create image dataset in Pytorch with png format images

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

People mostly use csv files to create dataset. My question is Can we create our own dataset in pytorch (without using ImageFolder) with the images in the format .png or .tif.
If yes, can somebody show me the code for that.
I need to create my own dataset in pytorch. I'm having images in the format .tif.

Comment: What is your dataset directory structure?

Comment: @Ivan My dataset folder contains 2 folders (testing and training). Each folders contains 22 sub folders each. Those 22 are my classes. Each class contains several number of images.

Comment: Why not use `ImageFolder` exactly?

Comment: @Ivan I want to split my training set into labeled and unlabeled data sets. I need to do  some random rotation on unlabeled data set. The purpose is to predict the labels of unlabeled dataset. Can we do all these using **ImageFolder**

Comment: You didn't mention having unlabeled images before, can you clarify?